# How do I conditionally use R packages in help file examples?

Tags: r

I'm an R package author, and I received a notice form CRAN that my package was going to be archived because the packages in my Suggests need to be used conditionally. In my main code, they are used conditionally; I wrote a `check.packages()` function that throws an error if the package is not able to be loaded. In the examples in my Help files, though, I simply attach the package with `library()`, which is likely where I made my mistake. The problem arose because a package I included in Suggests was archived.

My question is how do I conditionally use packages in examples in Help files? I tried using

```
ifelse{\Sexpr{isTRUE(requireNamespace("pkg"))}}{
#Example with pkg
}{
\dontrun{
#Example with pkg
}}
```

that is, if the package is loadable, display the example as usual, and if not, wrap `\dontrun{}` around it. This worked when I previewed the Help file, but the CRAN check tells me I can't use `\ifelse` in examples. If it's important that my examples attach packages in my Suggests, is my only option to wrap `\dontrun` around all of them, regardless of whether the package can be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

CRAN were happy with a simple `if` statement in the vignette of one of my [packages](https://ms609.github.io/TreeDist/articles/using-distances.html):

```r
if (requireNamespace('pkg', quietly = TRUE)) {
  library('pkg')
  # Example with pkg
} else {
  message("'pkg' not available")
}
```

I could be missing something, but I can't see why this approach shouldn't work in examples too; perhaps you would need to add an `unloadNamespace('pkg')` after the example to clean up?